# Celery ValueError: Exception information must include the exception type

Tags: python, flask, redis, celery, celery-task

I got error while running task in celery.

I am running celery with command: `celery -A proj worker --loglevel=debug --pool=solo`

- Redis 7.0.12
- Celery 5.3.1
- Python 3.9
- kombu 5.3.1

I am getting this error:

```
raise ValueError("Exception information must include "
ValueError: Exception information must include the exception type

  warn(RuntimeWarning(

[2023-08-25 02:19:44,070: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: ValueError('Exception information must include the exception type')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 354, in exception_to_python
    exc_type = exc['exc_type']
KeyError: 'exc_type'
```

I tried to add try/except in tasks, but it didn't help.

Could you please tell me where is the problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was described [in this official Celery GitHub issue](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/8457#issuecomment-1713577407)

Basically the celery update_state() method awaiting some additional metadata on exceptions: 'exc_type' and 'exc_message'.

For me the solution looks like this:

```
self.update_state(state='FAILURE', meta={'exc_type': type(e).__name__,
                                         'exc_message': e.__str__(),                                                
                                         **self.task_progress.__dict__})
```

Some additional comments from the above GitHub issue also point at that it might be related to some redis-py version in the requirements.txt but fixing version isn't confirmed to help.

Let know if you have some progress with this or how you tackled this.